# Create Custom Tab Attribute in Customer Edit

Tags: magento

I'm trying to create a tab called Additonal in admin customer edit and place my custom employee attribute in it. Is this possible in via my modules sql setup? This question is relevant only to Magento >= 1.5.1.

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'employee', array(
    'type'              => 'int',
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'Employee Status',
    'input'             => 'select',
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => 'boilerplate/customer_attribute_status',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => false,
    'default'           => '',
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'unique'            => false
));

$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'employee');
$attribute->addData(array('sort_order'=>50));
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer'));
$attribute->save();
```

Below is not working. Here I'm trying to create a tab in backend admin customer edit and place my emploee attribute in it.

```
$entityTypeId = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeId  = $installer->getAttributeId('customer', 'employee');

$attributeSets = $installer->_conn->fetchAll('select * from '.$this->getTable('eav/attribute_set').' where entity_type_id=?', $entityTypeId);
foreach ($attributeSets as $attributeSet) {
    $setId = $attributeSet['attribute_set_id'];
    $installer->addAttributeGroup($entityTypeId, $setId, 'Additional');
    $groupId = $installer->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $setId, 'Additional');
    $installer->addAttributeToGroup($entityTypeId, $setId, $groupId, $attributeId);
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to add a tab in admin's customer edit view:

1. At your module's admin's layout's .xml file, put:

   ```
   <adminhtml_customer_edit>
       <reference name="customer_edit_tabs">
           <action method="addTab"><name>tabs_name</name><block>ModuleAlias/path_to_block_file</block></action>
       </reference>
   </adminhtml_customer_edit>
   ```
2. your block file should extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template` and implements `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface` (meaning that you'll have to implement some methods), and in the construct you can set the template file, ie:

   ```
   class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_History
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
   {
       public function __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
           $this->setTemplate('path/to/file.phtml');
       }

       //down here are the mandatory methods you have to include
       public function getTabLabel()
       {
           return Mage::helper('points')->__('Tab label');
       }

       public function getTabTitle()
       {
           return Mage::helper('points')->__('Tab title');
       }

       public function canShowTab()
       {
           if (Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId()) {
               return true;
           }
           return false;
       }

       public function isHidden()
       {
           if (Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId()) {
               return false;
           }
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your response but overloading the customer edit tab block isn't what I'm looking for. I'm trying to create a tab and point my attribute to it via my modules custom install.

Comment: this code isn't overloading anything and it does create a tab. You just have to put your attribute in it.

Comment: Sorry at first glance I thought you were just overloading the block but actually that's a new way of doing it I've never seen. Thanks :) I think in catalog/product you can use a module mysql setup but customer does not support that functionality. The setup script I'm using above does create the select inside the tab Additional Info which might be sufficient for now. I'm going to investigate it this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

You also can add AJAX tab instead of load all data with page

for example

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
        <reference name="product_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <id>mediagallery</id>
                <tab>
                    <label>MediaGallery</label>
                    <class>ajax</class>

                </tab>
            </action>
            <action method="setTabData">
                <id>mediagallery</id>
                <key>url</key>
                <value>*/catalog_product_mediagallery/index</value>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_mediagallery_index>
        <block type="mediagallery/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_gallery" name="root" output="toHtml" template="mediagallery/container.phtml">
        </block>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_mediagallery_index>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_mediagallery_image>
        <block type="mediagallery/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_gallery_image" name="root"></block>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_mediagallery_image>
</layout>
```

1. add tab link on handler
2. set Tab data to set correct url from wehre load conten
3. in controller you can render content or call layout as in my example

**adminhtml_catalog_product_mediagallery_index** - render content: grid contained and some custom buttons/

**adminhtml_catalog_product_mediagallery_image** - grid url for grid which was rendered in previous handle